# So … I think I just reviewed the same reopen queue entry twice …

Tags: bug, review-queues

I love the review queue, and I especially rejoice when the rarer reviews are available. Today was one such day where the reopen queue made its appearance.

Well, so I reviewed one edited closed question. Of course, it was a homework one that hadn’t been improved at all, so [leave closed](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/42197).

And then a few hours later [the same question and the same edit reappear in the review queue](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/42199). Wait, what happened here?

Answer (score 6):

I think I can shed some light in here. Note that my [timeline for this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/58901/timeline) is a bit more extensive. First the question was closed. Then the OP edited the question a few hours later which caused it to enter the reopen review queue. This review was completed with "leave closed". After that the question gained a reopen vote, which again caused it to enter the review queue. This review was again completed with "leave closed".

It's probably not the best situation when the same question gets reviewed by the same user multiple times. I think that may have been addressed at meta.SE, but I'm not sure and right now too busy to look for it. For the time being, I would recommend using the skip button, if the same question pops up again.

Comment: Somehow makes sense. The only thing I would still be confused about is why both said *this question was edited after it was closed.* But I guess the system just checks whether an edit happened after closure and then sets a flag …